# why isn't this coldfusion query not working?

Tags: sql, coldfusion, cfquery

I am having an issue with trying to update an SQL table with this cfquery. Here is the code in cold fusion:

```
    <CFSET dateTimes=DateFormat(Now(),"mm\dd\yyyy")>
    <CFQUERY NAME="updateTime" DATASOURCE="#this_datasource#">
        UPDATE users
        SET ACTIVITYDATE = CAST(#dateTimes# AS smalldatetime)
        WHERE username = '#Form.login_username#'
        AND Password = '#Form.Password#'
    </CFQUERY>
```

When trying to execute this it gives me this:

```
    Error Executing Database Query. [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]   [SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near '\25'. 
    The error occurred on line 19.
```

Also another thing is the type of sal_var the ACTIVITYDATE is smalldatetime. I have also tried doing it without the cast and just doing the plain #dateTimes# var. I have also tried the cfqueryparam which also did not work. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You should use `cfqueryparam` for the values you are entering into the DB. You can then get rid of the `CAST()`.

Comment: I have tried that with cfsqltype equal to cf_sql_date, but even that didn't work. I will play around with the different types I guess.

Comment: try `cf_sql_timestamp'

Comment: You should be using `cfqueryparam` for the username and password as well.

Comment: use single quotes around the date '#dateTimes#'

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I believe you need to be using forward slashes instead of back slashes. Also, as previously expressed, use cfqueryparams and no CAST.

Comment: ok well I just got out of work, so I will have to try tomorrow. If I have any other problems I will post again on here and thank everyone for helping.

Comment: Arguably more important than the lack of cfqueryparam (though that is an important issue) is that you're storing the password in plaintext - which is something that should ***never*** be done.

Comment: Don't use `dateFormat()` when passing a date to a DB. Use a date object (in your case just `now()` is fine). Also - as others have said  - do not hardcode your parameter values into your SQL string, pass them as parameters with `<cfqueryparam>`. Do all that first, then let's have a look at your error(s)...

Comment: I did not notice that. @PeterBoughton is absolutely right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cfqueryparam cfsqltype to use for SQL Server datetime / smalldatetime values is cf_sql_timestamp.  You can re-write the code as follows:

```
<CFSET dateTimes=DateFormat(Now(),"mm/dd/yyyy")>
<CFQUERY NAME="updateTime" DATASOURCE="#this_datasource#">
    UPDATE users
    SET ACTIVITYDATE = <cfqueryparam value="#dateTimes#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp">
    WHERE username = <cfqueryparam value="#Form.login_username#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    AND Password = <cfqueryparam value="#Form.Password#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">;
</CFQUERY>
```

Using cfqueryparam is recommended to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.

See: https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfqueryparam

Comment: The dateTimes variable is a string, not a dateobject.  If a ColdFusion value is to be passed to the db, now() is the appropriate value.

Comment: ColdFusion will convert a string to a date - assuming it is in a common date format -  when it passes data to the database with `cfqueryparam`

Comment: it seemed like this way of doing it worked. I have to double check with the DB as soon I get access, but I did a test query in the code to check the activity date and it gave back the correct activity date :-).

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
SET ACTIVITYDATE = CAST(#dateTimes# AS smalldatetime)
```

to this:

```
SET ACTIVITYDATE = GetDate()
```

or, if you don't want the time component

```
SET ACTIVITYDATE = cast(GetDate() as date)
```

While you can send a ColdFusion variable, it's not necessary so why bother?

Comment: `cfqueryparam>` should always be used.

Comment: Not when using database functions to get the current date and time.

Comment: it's still a good habit to get into especially when the user has posted no queryparam's in their code at all.

Comment: @SovrSow - Just to clarify, you should always use `cfqueryparam` with variables like in your original example. Primarily to prevent sql injection, but it has other benefits as well. However, it *cannot* be used when the value is a database function like `getDate()`. The reason is `cfqueryparam` prevents sql from being executed, so those two are mutually exclusive.